# CSS: Table multiple column to single column

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>phone no</th>
 <th>address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Nadia</td>
 <td>012-4532564</td>
 <td>no 6,ampang, selangor, malaysia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>osman</td>
 <td>017-25698744</td>
 <td>no 20 street 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

above is my html coding, so the output will be

```
name | phone no     | address
------------------------------------------------------
nadia| 012-4532564  | no 6,ampang, selangor, malaysia
-----------------------------------------------------
osman| 017-25698744 | no 20 street 3
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want using CSS to give the output like below...

```
-----------------------------------
| nadia                           |
| 012-4532564                     |
| no 6,ampang, selangor, malaysia |
-----------------------------------
| osman                           | 
| 017-25698744                    |
| no 20 street 3                  |
-----------------------------------
```

if using HTML we can use the colspan..  already search code using CSS, I found the column-span but it not working at all...  I insisted on using `table tag` instead of `div` and only using CSS... it's more like I want the table to be the responsive template...

Comment: why don't you, use a div if you want this kind of output??

Answer (score 2):

You can *break* the table `display` and change it to `block` - see a demo below:

```css
table {
  display: block;
}
tr > th {
  display: none;
}

tr > td {
  display: block;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>phone no</th>
 <th>address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Nadia</td>
 <td>012-4532564</td>
 <td>no 6,ampang, selangor, malaysia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>osman</td>
 <td>017-25698744</td>
 <td>no 20 street 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr{
  border-top : 1px dotted #000;
  border-bottom : 1px dotted #000;
}
table tr td{
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>

<tr>
 <td>Nadia</td>
 <td>012-4532564</td>
 <td>no 6,ampang, selangor, malaysia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>osman</td>
 <td>017-25698744</td>
 <td>no 20 street 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```